# Free / Open Source Windows Fortran Compiler Compatible with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fortran

I'm trying to link in some legacy Fortran code with a Visual Studio C++ project.  I tried using the Windows build of gfortran to build my static library but Visual Studio complains about unresolved external symbols.  I guessing this is because mixing mingw and visual studio compilers is a horrible, horrible idea.

I've googled a bit and I see my options are [Intel's](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-compilers/) and [Lahey's](http://www.lahey.com/) compilers but both carry a hefty price tag.

Does anyone know of other options, or a different approach I can take?

**EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS**

The error I'm getting is:

> Error 7   error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol ___chkstk referenced
>   in function *fmm*

Searching around led me to [this](http://eegeerg.blogspot.com/2008_01_01_archive.html#4158852069709002699), which just seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Visual C++ can link to other compiler's DLLs, so what exactly are the errors you are getting? Are they functions from runtime libs or `_your_fortran_function` or mangled names?

Comment: I second the suggestion to show us the errors.  Fortran compilers typically name-mangle routine names with underscores to avoid conflict with C routines.  You may need to override this to combine Fortran and C/C++.  A recent related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985819/gfortran-dll-underscore

Comment: @Pete and @M.S.B, see edits above, thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go the old-school route and use `f2c` to translate your legacy Fortran to standard K&R C which you should be able to build with the MSFT toolchain.

I have not used `f2c` in many moons and recall it being a tad picky and a pain to work with. As `g77` and later `gfortan` became so much better, there was less and less need to use it.

That said, for your legacy needs it sounds like a good fit.  The [Wikipedia entry on f2c](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F2c) also contains a link to the [f2c sources](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/) at [Netlib](http://www.netlib.org).

*Edit:* This may not free you from the run-time requirements though -- your C++ app may need to be linked to the f2c runtime.

Comment: @Dirk, excellent idea.  The actually worked without any additional linking, all I needed was the f2c.h.  If you don't mind, I'm not going to accept your answer yet, I want to see if any more answers get posted. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting.  As I said, I used it many many moons ago and mostly on Linux where linking with -lf2c was de rigeur.  Maybe the frontend got better, more complete or you just got lucky with the MSFT libs.