# GCC Merge two differents object files to one object file

Tags: c, gcc, fortran, static-linking, gfortran

```
 // f.for is a Fortran source file
 // c.c is a C source file   
 # gfortran -c f.for            // produce f.o
 # gcc -c c.c                   // produce c.o
```

since **f.for** calls some functions from **c.c**. How can I produce a third object file **fc.o** which will be used later to generate an executable with another C source code. explain:

```
 # gcc/gfortran? (or other) -?? f.o c.o -o fc.o
 # gcc -o executable source.c fc.o
```

thank you

What I have done but not work:

```
  # ar rvs fc.a f.o c.o  
  # gcc -o executable source.c fc.a
```

But it shows me error like : **undefined reference to 'function_name_X'.** function_name_X is in f.for

Comment: `ar rvs fc.a f.o c.o` will get you a static library (`fc.a`), which you can use as if it were an object file made by merging `f.o` and `c.o`.

Comment: PSkocik: Yes, I'll try again this solution, perhaps it is the unique solution

Comment: Have you tried `ld -r f.o c.o -o fc.o`, then? (Dark Falcon's link)

Comment: You may be asking the wrong question.  If you're producing all these object files in the same build process, then you don't need to make a combined object file.  You can just link all the needed object files together to produce the final executable.

Comment: John Bollinger -> I have this this idea in my mind: if a.o depends on b.o, c.c depends on a.o , so # gcc -o exe c.c a.o b.o will work?

Answer (score 2):

Credit: PSkocik, John Bollinger
My comment :

> I have this this idea in my mind: if a.o depends on b.o, c.c depends
>   on a.o , so # gcc -o exe c.c a.o b.o will work?

should works. In fact, I listed all functions in **f.o** :

```
 # nm f.o
```

I find that Fortran add underscore '_' at the end of every function name, since I'm calling these functions from C without adding underscore at end, this error happened. 
According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985819/gfortran-dll-underscore): I added **-fno-underscoring** to **gfortran** compiler when generating **f.o**

```
# gfortran -c f.for -fno-underscoring
# nm f.o
```

at this time, there is no underscore at the end.
Response to the question:

```
# gcc -o executable source.c f.o c.o  // not need fc.o
```